# IE link opens a new window when running Robot Tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, robotframework

im having an issue when im running my robot tests.

The application under test (AUT) has a button that opens a new tab when you click it. It works on Chrome and IE when a user actually clicks that button. However, when i run my test to test that functionality in IE, the test opens a new window and that window is not being recognized (i used the SELECT WINDOW keyword in selenium2library)

Has anybody encountered this? is this an IE11 issue or IEWebDriver issue or something?

Here is my system specs:

- OS - Windows 7
- Browser - IE11
- Robot Framework Version - 3.0.2
- IEDriverServer version - 3.4

Thank you. i hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run your test in IE the test opens a `New Window` instead of a new `TAB` is actually **perfect**.

As per @JimEvans on the github issue [**`Selenium 3.7.1-IEDriverServer 3.7.0 : IEDriverServer opens a new Window instead of new TAB when JavascriptExecutor is used`**](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5108) :

```
This is by design that a new window is opened.
```

Comment: i have no issue with this but i cant seem to select that new window using the SELECT WINDOW keyword in selenium2library. when i used the keyword GET WINDOW NAMES and GET WINDOW IDENTIFIER keywords, it only shows 1 window. 

and when the test is done, i have a Close All Browser on the Suite Teardown, and the newly opened window is not closing. are these also expected behaviors for the IEDriverServer?